# Cube of math in equations

Tags: equations, draw, commutative-diagrams

How did they make the "cube of math" images in equations on pages 219, 222, 223, etc. of this article?
https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v159-n1-p03.pdf

Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There are several ways to do that. You can take a look at the `tikz-cd` package, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first define a simple command `crossingover` with 5 parameters: #2-#5 are nodes/coordinates for 2 segments and #1 for thickness of crossing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\crossingover[#1](#2,#3,#4,#5){%
\path (intersection of #2--#3 and #4--#5) coordinate (#2#3#4#5);
\draw (#2)--(#3);
\draw[shorten >=#1] (#4)--(#2#3#4#5);
\draw[shorten >=#1] (#5)--(#2#3#4#5);
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) coordinate (A) node[left]{A}
(2,2) coordinate (B) node[right]{B}
(2,0) coordinate (C) node[right]{C}
(0,2) coordinate (D) node[left]{D};
\crossingover[2mm](A,B,C,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then things become straight forward.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\crossingover[#1](#2,#3,#4,#5){
\path (intersection of #2--#3 and #4--#5) coordinate (#2#3#4#5);
\draw (#2)--(#3);
\draw[shorten >=#1] (#4)--(#2#3#4#5);
\draw[shorten >=#1] (#5)--(#2#3#4#5);
}
\def\a{2} % length of a side of the cube
\begin{document}
$$ A_{{\rm id},D}=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=1cm]
\path 
(0,0) node (A) {$1$} +(90:\a) node (A') {$0$}
(\a,0) node (B) {$0$} +(90:\a) node (B') {$1$}
(.8,.8) node (D) {$0$} +(90:\a) node (D') {$1$}
++(0:\a) node (C) {} +(90:\a) node (C') {$0$};
\foreach \p/\q in {A/B,A/D,A/A',B/C,A'/D',B'/C',C/C',C'/D'} 
\draw (\p)--(\q);
\crossingover[1mm](B,B',C,D)
\crossingover[1mm](A',B',D,D')
% small tranlating the label to the right
\path (C) node[right=-1.5mm,fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{$D/4$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad \mbox{or} \quad
A_{{\rm id},D}=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=1cm]
\path 
(0,0) node (A) {$1$} +(90:\a) node (A') {$0$}
(\a,0) node (B) {$1$} +(90:\a) node (B') {$1$}
(.8,.8) node (D) {$1$} +(90:\a) node (D') {$1$}
++(0:\a) node (C) {} +(90:\a) node (C') {$1$};
\foreach \p/\q in {A/B,A/D,A/A',B/C,A'/D',B'/C',C/C',C'/D'} 
\draw (\p)--(\q);
\crossingover[1mm](B,B',C,D)
\crossingover[1mm](A',B',D,D')
% small tranlating the label to the right
\path (C) node[right=-3mm,fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{$(D+3)/4$};
\end{tikzpicture}
$$
\end{document}
```

**Update** I guess OP wants (math) texts go through the centers of cubes. To do that, I remove the `[baseline]` option, and put

```
\path (intersection of A--D' and D--A')
+(-.5,0) node[left]{$A_{{\rm id},D}=$};
```

The new code with cubes of smaller sides `a=1.6`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} %<<< for dummy text only
\def\crossingover[#1](#2,#3,#4,#5){%
\path (intersection of #2--#3 and #4--#5) coordinate (#2#3#4#5);
\draw (#2)--(#3);
\draw[shorten >=#1] (#4)--(#2#3#4#5);
\draw[shorten >=#1] (#5)--(#2#3#4#5);
}%
\def\a{1.6} % length of a side of the cube
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]  
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) node (A) {$1$} +(90:\a) node (A') {$0$}
(\a,0) node (B) {$0$} +(90:\a) node (B') {$1$}
(.8,.8) node (D) {$0$} +(90:\a) node (D') {$1$}
++(0:\a) node (C) {} +(90:\a) node (C') {$0$};
\foreach \p/\q in {A/B,A/D,A/A',B/C,A'/D',B'/C',C/C',C'/D'} 
\draw (\p)--(\q);
\crossingover[1mm](B,B',C,D)
\crossingover[1mm](A',B',D,D')
% small tranlating the label to the right
\path (C) node[right=-1.5mm,fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{$D/4$};
\path (intersection of A--D' and D--A')
+(-.5,0) node[left]{$A_{{\rm id},D}=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) node (A) {$1$} +(90:\a) node (A') {$0$}
(\a,0) node (B) {$1$} +(90:\a) node (B') {$1$}
(.8,.8) node (D) {$1$} +(90:\a) node (D') {$1$}
++(0:\a) node (C) {} +(90:\a) node (C') {$1$};
\foreach \p/\q in {A/B,A/D,A/A',B/C,A'/D',B'/C',C/C',C'/D'} 
\draw (\p)--(\q);
\crossingover[1mm](B,B',C,D)
\crossingover[1mm](A',B',D,D')
% small tranlating the label to the right
\path (C) node[right=-3mm,fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{$(D+3)/4$};
\path (intersection of A--D' and D--A')
+(-.5,0) node[left]{or \quad $A_{{\rm id},D}=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am new to this, and when I rewrote what you had to experiment (I re-ordered the nodes), the cube itself looked fine, but was no longer vertically centered. Is there something special in there I am not noticing which controls the bounding boxes or centering somehow?

Comment: @dwbarkley You mean horizontal, right? (because I don't see anything vertical). If so, in 2 `tikzlicture` I used the same option `[baseline=1cm]` (1cm here is the half of `\a=2` - the length of cubes),making them at the same hight (above the baseline).

Comment: vertical, in that the cube seems centered vertically on the line started with `A_{{\rm id},D}`

Comment: @dwbarkley I added an update. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

`tikz-cd` allows you to do that, see section **2.6 Three-dimensional diagrams** of its manual. The `crossing over` key makes an edge appear to be in the foreground.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
 A_{\mathrm{kl},D}=
 \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.5em,/tikz/column 2/.style={column sep=1.5em},
    row sep=0.5em,/tikz/row 2/.style={row sep=1.5em},
    /tikz/nodes={text width={width("1")}},
    every arrow/.append style={dash}]
  & 1\arrow[rr]\arrow[dd] \arrow[dl] & & 0 \arrow[dd]\arrow[ld]\\
  0\arrow[rr,crossing over]\arrow[dd] & & 1 & \\
  & 1 \arrow[rr]& &\! D/4 \\
  1 \arrow[ur]\arrow[rr]& & 0\arrow[uu,crossing over] \arrow[ur]& \\
 \end{tikzcd}\qquad\text{or}\quad
 A_{\mathrm{kl},D}=
 \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.5em,/tikz/column 2/.style={column sep=1.5em},
    row sep=0.5em,/tikz/row 2/.style={row sep=1.5em},
    /tikz/nodes={text width={width("1")}},
    every arrow/.append style={dash}]
  & 1\arrow[rr]\arrow[dd] \arrow[dl] & & 0 \arrow[dd]\arrow[ld]\\
  0\arrow[rr,crossing over]\arrow[dd] & & 1 & \\
  & 1 \arrow[rr]& &\! (D+3)/4 \\
  1 \arrow[ur]\arrow[rr]& & 1 \arrow[uu,crossing over] \arrow[ur]& \\
 \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to store the keys in a style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{3d matrix/.style={column sep=0.75em,
    row sep=0.75em,/tikz/row 2/.style={row sep=2em},
    /tikz/nodes={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt},
    every arrow/.append style={dash}},
    extra/.style={execute at end picture={#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
 A_{\mathrm{id},D}=
 \begin{tikzcd}[3d matrix,extra={\node[anchor=west,inner sep=1pt]
 at (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-4.west){$D/4$};}]
  & 1\arrow[rr]\arrow[dd] \arrow[dl] & & 0 \arrow[dd]\arrow[ld]\\
  0\arrow[rr,crossing over]\arrow[dd] & & 1 & \\
  & 1 \arrow[rr]& & \phantom{0}  \\
  1 \arrow[ur]\arrow[rr]& & 0\arrow[uu,crossing over] \arrow[ur]& \\
 \end{tikzcd}\quad\text{or}\quad
 A_{\mathrm{id},D}=
 \begin{tikzcd}[3d matrix,extra={\node[anchor=west,inner sep=1pt]
 at (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-4.west){$(D+3)/4$};}]
  & 1\arrow[rr]\arrow[dd] \arrow[dl] & & 0 \arrow[dd]\arrow[ld]\\
  0\arrow[rr,crossing over]\arrow[dd] & & 1 & \\
  & 1 \arrow[rr]& &\phantom{0} \\
  1 \arrow[ur]\arrow[rr]& & 1 \arrow[uu,crossing over] \arrow[ur]& \\
 \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks. What is going on with the "anchor=west", "execute and end of picture", stuff? I'll definitely need to play with this a bit to learn more.

Comment: @dwbarkley This is a trick to add a larger node to the matrix without distorting it. So we add the node after the matrix is "done" into the cell filled with the \phantom{0}`. The first example achieves this by choosing a small `text width` but this causes overfull \hbox warnings and that the node is not taken into account for the determination of the bounding box.