# Problems with order in crossings tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I need to draw the following diagram

[image]

but I don't know how to use  `crossing over` in order to make the arrow that goes from C to B cross over the rest.

- Is it possible to do so?

Here is my code. How should I modify it assuming it is possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
& A \arrow{rr} \arrow{d} & & B \arrow{d} \\
C \arrow{ur} \arrow[bend right = 50]{urrr} \arrow{d} & D \arrow{rr}& & E\\
F \arrow{ur} \arrow[bend right = 50]{urrr} & & &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not understand your problem. The code and the image match perfectly. What do you want to change?

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible to draw the arrow that goes from C to B in such a way that it crosses over the rest of the arrows using crossing over.

Comment: And, if so, how should I modify my code. I don't want to change anything else, just make that arrow cross over the arrows FD and DE.

Comment: @Zarko I don't see how this post can help me :(

Comment: @Zarko I couldn't find anything, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Zarko You must have entered the wrong link, there is nothing with `crossing over` to this question.

Comment: huh, correct link is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529685/cube-of-math-in-equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build this arrow last using absolute placement.

```
\arrow[from=2-1,to=1-4,bend right = 50,crossing over]{urrr}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
& A \arrow{rr} \arrow{d} & & B \arrow{d} \\
C \arrow[ur]  \arrow{d} & D \arrow[rr]& & E\\
F \arrow[ur] \arrow[bend right = 50]{urrr} & & &
\arrow[from=2-1,to=1-4,bend right = 50,crossing over]{urrr}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! Thanks a lot !!! :)